# Android login using Volley, PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I am trying to create a login using Volley. It seems that i was able to connect to my database since it displays the "success" message in my PHP code but i cannot get pass the login page after putting in the correct credentials from the database. I have displayed the php response in my logcat. It is quite unclear to me what is happening because i have tried using another trial URL to connect to my api with the same content and it works. but when i use the url indicated in my `SessionManagement` class, it does not work. Can someone please help

Login.java

```
package com.example.merylle.themoneyger.activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.example.merylle.themoneyger.HttpParse;
import com.example.merylle.themoneyger.R;
import com.example.merylle.themoneyger.SessionManagement;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class Login extends Activity {
    TextView title;
    Typeface marcellus;
    EditText emailuser, passworduser;
    TextView forgot;
    Button login, register;
    private boolean loggedIn = false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        /*session = new SessionManagement(getApplicationContext());*/

        title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        marcellus = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"marcellus.ttf");
        title.setTypeface(marcellus);

        emailuser = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
        passworduser = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
        login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        forgot = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtForgotPW);
        register = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                /*CheckEditTextIsEmpty();*/
                login();
            }
        });

        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent registration = new Intent(Login.this, Registration.class);
                startActivity(registration);
            }
        });

        forgot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent forgot = new Intent(Login.this, ForgotPassword.class);
                startActivity(forgot);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //In onresume fetching value from sharedpreference
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SessionManagement.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        //Fetching the boolean value form sharedpreferences
        loggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(SessionManagement.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, false);

        //If we will get true
        if(loggedIn){
            //We will start the Profile Activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    private void login(){
        //Getting values from edit texts
        final String email = emailuser.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password = passworduser.getText().toString().trim();

        //Creating a string request
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, SessionManagement.LOGIN_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        //If we are getting success from server
                        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase(SessionManagement.LOGIN_SUCCESS)){
                            //Creating a shared preference
                            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = Login.this.getSharedPreferences(SessionManagement.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                            //Creating editor to store values to shared preferences
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                            //Adding values to editor
                            editor.putBoolean(SessionManagement.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, true);
                            editor.putString(SessionManagement.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF, email);

                            //Saving values to editor
                            editor.commit();

                            //Starting profile activity
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }else{
                            //If the server response is not success
                            //Displaying an error message on toast
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Invalid username/password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.e("volley", response);
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //You can handle error here if you want
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                //Adding parameters to request
                params.put(SessionManagement.KEY_EMAIL, email);
                params.put(SessionManagement.KEY_PASSWORD, password);

                //returning parameter
                return params;
            }
        };

        //Adding the string request to the queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

SessionManagement.java

```
public class SessionManagement {

    //URL to our login.php file
    public static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:63343/TheMoneyger/api/user-login.php";


    //Keys for email and password as defined in our $_POST['key'] in login.php
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";

    //If server response is equal to this that means login is successful
    public static final String LOGIN_SUCCESS = "success";

    //Keys for Sharedpreferences
    //This would be the name of our shared preferences
    public static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "themoneygerapp";

    //This would be used to store the email of current logged in user
    public static final String EMAIL_SHARED_PREF = "email";

    //We will use this to store the boolean in sharedpreference to track user is loggedin or not
    public static final String LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF = "loggedin";
}
```

user-login.php

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    //Getting values
    $username = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    //Creating sql query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$username' AND password='$password'";

    //importing dbConnect.php script
    require_once('config.php');

    //executing query
    $result = mysqli_query($database,$sql);

    //fetching result
    $check = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    //if we got some result
    if(isset($check)){
        //displaying success
        echo "success";
    }else{
        //displaying failure
        echo "failure";
    }
    mysqli_close($database);
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the value of `SessionManagement.LOGIN_SUCCESS`?

Comment: @ChrisStillwell LOGIN_SUCCESS="success". I have edited the code above and added the class for my keys

Comment: any logcat errors？

Comment: @navylover no error in logcat. i printed out the response in php to check for errors and it prints out "success". it always goes to the my "else" block of code in creating the string request. else{
                            //If the server response is not success
                            //Displaying an error message on toast
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Invalid username/password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.e("volley", response);
                        }

Comment: it is quite unclear to me what is happening because i have tried using another trial URL to connect to my api with the same content and it works. but when i use the url indicated in my SessionManagement class, it does not work.

Comment: What show the `Logcat` if you put `Log.d("volley", response);` after the `onResponse`

`@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
 Log.d("volley", response);
......`

Comment: @A.Palacio i already did what you said and put the Log.d("volley", response) after the onResponse.  "E/volley: success" is printed in my logcat. But the toast says "Invalid username/password"

Comment: Try to validate in this way
`if(response.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(SessionManagement.LOGIN_SUCCESS)){
.....`

Comment: @A.Palacio thanks your solution worked perfectly! May i know why this was happening and why adding .trim() did the trick?

Comment: Somehow, the response coming from the server adds spaces to the chain. The function `trim()` removes the leading and trailing white characters of the string. Sorry, my English is bad :).